# How can I have custom content as last page?

Tags: 8, views

I have a view which shows nodes of 3 specific content types. The content shown is coming from the parent node with entity reference fields where the nodes can be selected to be shown in the view.

I was wondering how I could add custom content, or maybe a node to the end of a that view without having to select it on the parent, because this is always the same content.

What I want is like have the view display a node or some programmatically custom content. It should be there as last page. For example I have a view with 4 nodes, the pager should show 5 and have the 5th page be the node/content I want. I don't want to have to add it every time on the parent node with the entity reference field. It should be there by default.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to add a footer to your view. If you are on the admin screen for your view, you should see options for Page Settings, Header, and Footer in the middle column.

[image: View admin screen showing where to add content to footer region]

If you "Add" content to the Footer area it will always output below your view content. There are several options including to display a rendered node.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This could be a solution. This is not exactly what i want, what i want is like have the view display a node or some programatticaly custom content. It should be there as last page. For example i have a view with 4 nodes, the pager should show 5 and have the 5th item be the node/content i want. I dont want to have to add it every time on the parent node with the entity reference field. It should be there by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating your own views template file in themes/custom/MYTHEME_NAME/templates. See this documentation for naming conventions
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.6.x

In my case, I am using the [Views Bootstrap Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) and wanted to change the template of a view which uses the Bootstrap Grid mode. So I copied `views-bootstrap-grid.html.twig` from the module's directory (/modules/contrib/views_bootstrap/templates) into my theme's template directory and renamed it to `views-bootstrap-grid--companies--block.html.twig`

Inside the template file, I added the needed html code:

```
{#
/**
 * @file views-bootstrap-grid.html.twig
 * Default simple view template to display Bootstrap Grids.
 *
 *
 * - columns: Contains rows grouped by columns.
 * - rows: Contains a nested array of rows. Each row contains an array of
 *   columns.
 * - column_type: Contains a number (default Bootstrap grid system column type).
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
#}
{%
  set classes = [
    'views-view-grid',
  ]
%}
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
<div id="{{ id }}" {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  <div class="row">
    {% for row in rows %}
      <div {{ row_attributes.addClass(options.row_class) }}>
        {{ row }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="my_custom_text">
        MY CUSTOM TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```